# How to get a list of check box IDs

Tags: c#, checkbox

I have created a web page that dynamically creates a table. one of the columns in the table is a checkbox that has an ID(int). I want to use the IDs of all the checked boxes in a SQL Query like so:

```
select * 
from table 
where ID in (1,2,3,4)
```

is there a way that I can get a list of the IDs from all of the checked boxes?

I am using C#.Net

here is a snippet of the code im using to generate the checkbox:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    string Compatible_Controls = (
        "<tr>" +
        "<td><input type='CheckBox' ID='" +(dr["id"]) + "' /></td>" +
        "<td>" + (dr["Control_Name"]) + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + (dr["Control_Statement"]) + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + (dr["Regulation_type"]) + "</td>" +
        "</tr> );
```

Here is what is generated:

```
<tr>
    <td><input type='CheckBox' ID='3' /></td>
    <td>xxxxxx</td>
    <td>xxxxxxxxx</td>
    <td>xxxxxxxx</td>
</tr>
```

thank you very much!!!!!

Comment: Is this an ASP.net web page?

Comment: It will be easier if you show us a little of the code you use to generate the web page, or else the HTML that shows up in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is **not tested**, but the basic logic should be correct. The idea is to loop through all the controls on the page, picking out the ones whose ID begins with a set prefix.

First, put a prefix before the numeric IDs:

```
string ID_Prefix = "MyCheckbox_";

string Compatible_Controls = (
                 "<tr>" +
                      "<td><input type='CheckBox' ID='" + ID_prefix 
                                + (dr["id"]) + "' /></td>" +
                      "<td>" + (dr["Control_Name"]) + "</td>" +
                      "<td>" + (dr["Control_Statement"]) + "</td>" +
                      "<td>" + (dr["Regulation_type"]) + "</td>" +
                "</tr> );
```

This will create HTML like this:

```
<td><input type='CheckBox' ID='MyCheckbox_3' /></td>
```

Now call this when you want to parse the page:

```
List<string> GetMyCheckboxes(ControlCollection coll, List<string> ids)
{
    foreach (Control ctl in coll)
    {
        if (ctl.ID.StartsWith(ID_Prefix))
            ids.Add(ctl.ID.Substring(ID_Prefix.Length)); // only take the number

        if (ctl.Controls.Count > 0)
            ids = GetInputs(ctl.Controls, ids);
    }
    return ids;
}
```

Call it like this:

```
List<string> ids = GetMyCheckboxes(Page.Controls, new List<string>());
```

You'll end up with a list containing just the IDs.

Answer (score 0):

If you name all the checkboxes the same thing, set the value of the checkbox to be the id, and have your controller accept a list of ints, it will pass back the checkboxes that are checked.

Like this:

View:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='check' value='1'>
<input type='checkbox' name='check' value='2'>
<input type='checkbox' name='check' value='3'>
<input type='checkbox' name='check' value='4'>
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult CheckBoxes(IList<int> checkIds)
{
  //checkIds will contain the "value" of all the checkboxes that are checked when the form is submitted.
}
```

Comment: He seems to be saying that all the checkboxes have different IDs.

Comment: They can have different html ids, as long as they have the same html name. You could also set the html value to equal the html id, so that you get a list of unique ids for the checkbox.

Comment: Melanie, Yes, This is an asp.net page. Taylonr, will this work outside of MVC?

Comment: I have no idea. I doubt it.